# How to pass question and answer of a quiz to next activity?

Tags: android-studio

[image: This is what i am looking for "The ACTIVITY D"]
I am making a quiz app in which user gets 5 questions to attempt . Each question appears in the screen one after other in 10 seconds interval. After the quiz is over , and when user press Check performance button ,i want to show the user his Self Evaluation Report of all the questions and options that appeared on his screen In activity B and what he selected the option and what was the right answer. So far i have managed to  displayed all the question and answer successfully by firestore database(Activity B is done). . But my problem is that how make list of all the Questions , options , selected option , correct option ,and show it in Activity D (checking activity). I dont want to use Firestore database again for this..

Answer (score 0):

I thing you can store your data in [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). If there is only 10 questions you can store it in separate value key or create class with all options witch can be serialized to json and store it in one key value field.

Comment: What do you mean by 10 questions? Each set of game has 4 question..